# Why beacons cause Bluetooth to continuously toggle?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ibeacon

I am experiencing a really weird bug working with iOS and iBeacon. I have a really simple `BeaconManager` that ranges beacons with particular UUID, major and minor values and performs some actions once it found them. My app seems to work properly until it continuously toggle the Bluetooth status and stop doing its job. The only visible result is that the Bluetooth icon in the status bar start flickering due to Bluetooth stopping and restarting.

Where to focus attention?

This is my class definition:

```
#import "BeaconManager.h"

@implementation BeaconManager

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSURL *beep = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"beep" withExtension:@"aiff"];
        soundFileURLRef = (CFURLRef) CFBridgingRetain(beep);
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundFileObject);

        // Initializes properties
        beacon = [CLBeacon new];
        foundBeacons = [NSMutableArray new];
        _lastBeaconActionTimes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)initRegion {
    // Initializes the beacon region by giving it an UUID and an identifier
    NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:BEACON];
    beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid identifier:@"beacon.region"];
    // Starts looking for beacon within the region
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:beaconRegion];
}

- (void)checkBeacon {
    if (!self.locationManager) {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;

        if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
            [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    [self initRegion];
    [self locationManager:self.locationManager didStartMonitoringForRegion:beaconRegion];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:beaconRegion];
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegion];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegion];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    [self.locationManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegion];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager monitoringDidFailForRegion:(CLRegion *)region withError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Failed monitoring region: %@", error);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Location manager failed: %@", error);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
        didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons
               inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {

    if (foundBeacons.count == 0) {
        for (CLBeacon *filterBeacon in beacons) {
            // If a beacon is located near the device and its major value is equal to 1000 (MAJOR constant)
            if (((filterBeacon.proximity == CLProximityImmediate) || (filterBeacon.proximity == CLProximityNear)))
                // Registers the beacon to the list of found beacons
                [foundBeacons addObject:filterBeacon];
        }
    }
    // Did some beacon get found?
    if (foundBeacons.count > 0) {
        // Takes first beacon of the list
        beacon = [foundBeacons firstObject];

        if (([beacon.major isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:MAJOR]]) && ([beacon.minor isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:MINOR]])) {
            // Takes the actual date and time
            NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
            NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", [beacon.proximityUUID UUIDString], beacon.major, beacon.minor];
            NSDate *lastBeaconActionTime = [_lastBeaconActionTimes objectForKey:key];
            if ((lastBeaconActionTime == nil) || ([now timeIntervalSinceDate:lastBeaconActionTime] > MINIMUM_ACTION_INTERVAL_SECONDS)) {
                [_lastBeaconActionTimes setObject:now forKey:key];
                // Plays beep sound
                AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundFileObject);

                if (self.delegate) {
                    // Performs actions related to the beacon (i.e. delivers a coupon)
                    [self.delegate didFoundBeacon:self];
                }
                self.locationManager = nil;
            }
            // else [self.locationManager stopMonitoringForRegion:region];
        }
        [foundBeacons removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        beacon = nil;
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: What device is that? Are you connected to any Bluetooth peripherals (e.g., a smart watch, or a Bluetooth headset)? When you say the icon is flickering, do you mean it's changing color, or that it keeps appearing and disappearing?

Comment: @heypiotr It's an iPhone 6 with iOS 8.3 and it's not connected to any other Bluetooth device. I also make a clean build of the app to avoid interferences. Bluetooth icon keeps appearing and disappearing very fast.

Comment: Any chance you could test your app on another device and see if it's the same? This looks slightly like a possible hardware issue. Are you using Core Location or some other beacon SDK?

Comment: @heypiotr Well, I'm not sure it would be a hardware issue because the bug also happens on an iPhone 4S with iOS 7.1.1. I'm using Core Location btw.

Comment: Are you repeatedly starting/stoping ranging? Are you performing any other location-related start/stop behaviors? Since it happens on multiple devices, it sounds to me like you're confusing the device (or perhaps doing exactly what your code is written to do, though probably not designed for ;-) ) in terms of responding to ranging and/or state changes. If you want to post code, please include how you set up your regions, any start/stop code, any state change handlers (including auth and/or hardware).

Comment: Provided the code for the manager class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't say for sure this is the reason why Bluetooth keeps toggling, but this part is definitely suspicious:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:beaconRegion];
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegion];
}
```

This is essentially an infinite loop. Once monitoring starts, iOS invokes the `didStartMonitoring` method … which starts monitoring for the very same region, which makes the iOS invoke the `didStartMonitoring` method again, which …

I'd start with removing the `startMonitoringForRegion` line from this part of your code.

Comment: OK, it seems to have a stabler behavior now. Anyway, Bluetooth still quickly toggles just once if I don't dismiss immediately the view controller associated with the `didFoundBeacon:` method. The view controller simply shows a label with a modal segue and a button that dismiss the view controller. For testing purposes, the alert is shown every 60 secs, so if I don't dismiss it before timer runs out, the view controllers stack. For real usage the timer length should be greater (about 30 mins). Could it be a related issue?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I appreciate it.